# how to find average in the time series data

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time series data (minute-wise data). I want to calculate the average of every 30 minutes data using R and I don't want to calculate the moving average.

Data looks like:

```
      data              date
1   0.138685809     2016-08-13 15:17:01.152
2   1.724535157     2016-08-13 15:23:09.153
3   3.691574663     2016-08-13 15:29:17.139
4   11.225038913    2016-08-13 15:35:25.131
5   2.415299764     2016-08-13 15:41:33.132
6   0.569204804     2016-08-13 15:47:41.136
7   9.324725292     2016-08-13 15:53:49.137
8   17.232072439    2016-08-13 15:59:57.140
9   20.876006587    2016-08-13 16:06:05.140
10  10.911137327    2016-08-13 16:12:13.144
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer using data.table.
The idea is to create a column that gives an index for each 30 minutes slice, and then use the by function to calculate the mean on each slide.
It is efficient and takes two lines :

```
library(data.table)
DT <- setDT(yourdataframe)

DT[,datepos := as.POSIXct(date,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")] { just to have a standart format
DT[,datediffindex := as.numeric((datepos - .SD[1,datepos])/60 )%/% 30]
```

Here I create the column datediffindex that is the index for each 30 minute slice of data. SOI calculate the difference between the time column and its first value, I divide per 60 to make it minutes, and then take the integer of the division per 30, that is your index
Then we just need to do the mean for each value of index:

```
DT[, datamean := mean(data), by = datediffindex]
```

It gives what you want

```
          data                    date             datepos datediffindex  datamean
 1:  0.1386858 2016-08-13 15:17:01.152 2016-08-13 15:17:01             0  3.839027
 2:  1.7245352 2016-08-13 15:23:09.153 2016-08-13 15:23:09             0  3.839027
 3:  3.6915747 2016-08-13 15:29:17.139 2016-08-13 15:29:17             0  3.839027
 4: 11.2250389 2016-08-13 15:35:25.131 2016-08-13 15:35:25             0  3.839027
 5:  2.4152998 2016-08-13 15:41:33.132 2016-08-13 15:41:33             0  3.839027
 6:  0.5692048 2016-08-13 15:47:41.136 2016-08-13 15:47:41             1 11.782629
 7:  9.3247253 2016-08-13 15:53:49.137 2016-08-13 15:53:49             1 11.782629
 8: 17.2320724 2016-08-13 15:59:57.140 2016-08-13 15:59:57             1 11.782629
 9: 20.8760066 2016-08-13 16:06:05.140 2016-08-13 16:06:05             1 11.782629
10: 10.9111373 2016-08-13 16:12:13.144 2016-08-13 16:12:13             1 11.782629
```

Comment: Can we update date according to the average data?That is instead of having the same data mean for five different time zone can we update data frame like this: 2016-08-13 15:41:33             0  3.839027,2016-08-13 16:12:13             1 11.782629

Comment: Yes you can.
DT[, .SD[1,.(date,datediffindex,datamean)], by = datediffindex] will give you what you want: the .SD[1,.(variables)] gives you the variables in the first line of each broup defined by the by= datediffindex.
If the solution suits you you can accept it.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know about some very elegant solution but there is one possibility:

Lets's say that your data looks like this:

```
        value       date         time
1   0.1386858 2016-08-13 15:17:01.152
2   1.7245352 2016-08-13 15:23:09.153
3   3.6915747 2016-08-13 15:29:17.139
4  11.2250389 2016-08-13 15:35:25.131
5   2.4152998 2016-08-13 15:41:33.132
6   0.5692048 2016-08-13 15:47:41.136
7   9.3247253 2016-08-13 15:53:49.137
8  17.2320724 2016-08-13 15:59:57.140
9  20.8760066 2016-08-13 16:06:05.140
10 10.9111373 2016-08-13 16:12:13.144
```

From your character variable create times variable

```
library(chron)
data$time <- chron(times = data$time)
```

Calculate differences between times and then apply cumulative sum

```
time_spent <- c(0, cumsum(diff(data$time)))
data$time_spent <- chron(times = time_spent)
```

Then cut the `time_spent` variable into 30-minutes intervals

```
data$time_parts <- cut(data$time_spent, 
                       c(seq(times(0), max(data$time_spent), by = times(30/(60*24))), max(data$time_spent)), 
                       include.lowest = T)
```

And finally calculate the average value for each 30-minutes interval:

```
aggregate(data$value, by = list(data$time_parts), FUN = mean)
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** You can also find some inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185952/aggregate-the-time-series-data-by-average-function-with-time-prefrance-of-hh?rq=1)

Comment: when I'm executing the last line of code I'm getting the following error Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate and my code is:
dtframe_nw$time_parts <- cut(dtframe_nw$time_spent, 
                       c(seq(times(0), max(dtframe_nw$time_spent), by = times(30/(60*24))), max(dtframe_nw$time_spent)), 
                       include.lowest = T)
aggregate(dtframe_nw$value, by = list(dtframe_nw$time_parts), FUN = mean)

Comment: Check what is your `dtframe_nw`.